# Run PHP script on link click without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, styleswitching

Ok, so I've done a style switcher in php, and I'm using it as a hidden feature on my site, which is triggered when user types "teema", and a modal box will appear on the top of the page content and displaying the available themes.

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="teema.php?teema=default" class="ajaxLink">Normaali</a></li>
    <li><a href="teema.php?teema=superhero" class="ajaxLink">Superhero</a></li>
    <li><a href="teema.php?teema=spacelab" class="ajaxLink">Spacelab</a></li>
    <li><a href="teema.php?teema=united" class="ajaxLink">United</a></li>
    <li><a href="teema.php?teema=cyborg" class="ajaxLink">Cyborg</a></li>
</ul>
```

However, I want to change the theme without the page refreshing so the css should load on background. Here's the teema.php:

```
<?php
    $style = $_GET['teema'];
    setcookie("teema", $style, time()+604800);
    if(isset($_GET['js'])) {
        echo $style; 
    } 
    else{
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  
    }
?>
```

And the php on the index that checks the cookie:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_COOKIE['teema'])) $style = $_COOKIE['teema'];
else $style = 'default';
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/<? echo $style;?>.css" id="theme">
```

How could I load the new css on the background, and fade it over to the old css using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make an ajax request so the cookie will be returned

Using jQuery:

```
$('.ajaxLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var teemaUrl=this.href;
    var teema=teemaUrl.split('=').pop()
    $.get(teemaUrl, { js:true}, function(data){
       $('#theme').attr('href','css/'+ teema+'.css')

    })
});
```

This will parse the `teema` value from link `href` , make call to that `href` ( may need to add path info) and update `href` of link tag with ID=theme

Comment: Nope, it's sure prevents loading, but it doesn't replace the css without reload.

Comment: does your existing link tag have an ID? `alert( $('#theme').length)`

Comment: do you mean the css to be changed?

Comment: oops I made a mistake   `$('#theme').attr('href','css/'+ teema+'.css')`. I had wrong attribute and also forgot path and extension

Comment: Almost perfect! Is it possible to fade the new css to it?

Comment: no.. the browser will instantly call the new css file, have no control over it. You could fade the page in and out but there's no way to know the timing

Comment: Okay, then I'll just have to stick with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can give a response of JavaScript content type in the PHP file and manipulate the stylesheet.

#### Change the code this way:

```
<?php
    $style = $_GET['teema'];
    setcookie("teema", $style, time()+604800);
    if(isset($_GET['js'])) {
        // echo $style; 
    } 
    else{
     // header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  
    }
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
?>
document.getElementById("theme").setAttribute("href", "teema.css");
```

---

#### Using AJAX and PHP to change the theme.

Since you already use the `id="theme"` in your `<link />` tag, we can easily set the stuff in jQuery using AJAX.

So, you give a theme request this way:

```
$.getScript("theme.php?teema=theme");
```

And in the PHP:

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
$('#theme').attr('href', 'css/<?php echo $_GET['teema']; ?>');
```

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen Added the full answer. Sorry, by mistake pressed `Ctrl+Enter`.

Comment: yeah, but this just goes to http://site.com/teema.php?teema=united and has document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", "teema.css"); on it.

Comment: yeah, I use jQuery, as I added it in tags and asked how to do it with jQuery.

Comment: Woah... Can you gimme a moment, so that I can give you an updated solution?

Comment: `$.getScript` is not appropriate for an html response and doesn't add the `js` param needed in php. Also `link` is not an ID

Comment: @charlietfl Seriously, did you see the PHP output? It is a jQuery!

Comment: @PraveenKumar huh?  `document.getElementById("link")` assumes there is a tag with that ID. Making it more confusing than simply leaving the php the way it was

Comment: @charlietfl Yea lol, just noticed. Thanks. Update the answer. :)

Comment: I just don't get it, do what in plain english? :D

Answer (score 1):

Change the content of this link (`$('$#theme').attr('href', 'css/' + selectedtheme +'.css');`, and you can set cookie in javascript too (`document.cookie = 'theme=' + selectedtheme`)